# glob() is not searching folder

Tags: php, post, glob

I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Here is my code

index.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['a'])){
    $action = $_POST['a'];
} else if(isset($_GET['a'])){
    $action = $_GET['a'];
} else {
    $action = "home";
}


if($action == "home"){
    $frontImages = glob('assets/images/frontpage/*');
    include_once 'home.php';
}
?>
```

I `var_dump($frontImages)` inside of `homp.php` (which btw is showing just fine) but I'm getting that `$frontImages` is an undefined variable. Both the `index.php` file and `home.php` file is in the root folder and here is a image of the path directory:

[image]

So not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_POST['a']);` and `var_dump($_GET['a']);` ? Or even directly using `$frontImages = glob('assets/images/frontpage/*');include_once 'home.php';` without the if/else statements ... ?

Comment: Posting your entire code will help us better. To add, have you tried removing the `*`?

Comment: I've tried all the variable and all of them are displayed as undefined variables. Not sure what is wrong. All .php files are in ../bygg/

Comment: This is a very small project and I've just started with it not much more to show really.

Comment: Re-check your paths. Also, you're doing this via a form?

Comment: post the content of `home.php` and the rest, even though it seems to you that there is not much more to show

Comment: okay I found out that I was using the wrong url. I always thought that index.php file was invoked as default but somehow home.php was being displayed directly without going through my index.php file and its working now. Thanks for your time and inputs.

Comment: Great. So, kind of a `path` issue then, ?

Comment: To make it more beautiful use `glob(dirname(__FILE__).'/assets/images/frontpage/*')`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['a'])) {
    $action = $_GET['a'];
} else {
    $action = "home";
}


if($action == "home"){
    while($acImg = glob('assets/images/frontpage/*')) {
        $frontImages[] = $acImg;
    }
    include_once 'home.php';
}
?>
```

Now you have a Array but this works by me